# Jquery input.mask with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-inputmask

I want to implement simple jquery mask pluging using [jquery input.mask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask), however, i cannot make it work with regex. What i want to achieve is:

```
99:59:59
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sefhsoqd/3/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
$("#test").inputmask({
            mask: "99:59:59",
            definitions: {'5': {validator: "[0-5]"}}
    });
```

The validator is an expression. Telling the "5" in the mask string to contain only numerical characters from 0 to 5.

edit: changed '-' to ':'

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sefhsoqd/5/):

```
$('#test').inputmask('Regex', { 
    regex: "^[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$"
});
```

Comment: the only problem is Regex extension does not support placeholder, but for simple masks adding definitions as in @Buster response does. Using Regex as you suggest provides validation only.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script src="../js/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

 <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="trvl_amt" data-inputmask="'mask': '9{0,50}.9{0,2}'" data-mask placeholder="Travel Amount"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Up to 50 numeric places + 2 Decimal

Comment: any values between 50 numeric places and 2 Decimal Places